# How do you narrow locale/codepage context in modern PHP?

Tags: php, locale, setlocale

I have `php_mod` 7.2.31 running under LightSpeed, the environment locale is UTF8. [My very tiny test project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245387/php-mysql-beginner-any-tips-appreciated-on-the-approach/245396?noredirect=1#comment481922_245396) only need to work with ASCII data, however, because env. locale is UTF8, `ctype_alnum()` check is skewed now. I could resolve it by call to `setlocale()`, however, according to the docs `setlocale()` is unsafe in threaded environment:

> Warning The locale information is maintained per process, not per
> thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS,
> HHVM or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale
> settings while a script is running, though the script itself never
> called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in
> different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the
> process-wide locale using setlocale().

I guess this makes sense. Hosting is managed by my provider, so I dont know all the details about it but for safety sake I'm assuming it is multithreaded. How do people handle such cases? My guesses so far:

1. Give up and process everything in UTF/multibyte
2. Use preg_match() (as with any regex matching in every other language I assume it always slower then native string/character tools)
3. Use some clever mechanism to manage locales/charsets?

Comment: Use `#1` and always set locale, so there will be no _sudden change_

Comment: But the #1 implies you just work with UTF8. Can you elaborate what do you mean? How do you handle threaded environment? Examples also would be nice if possible

Comment: We always set locale at the beginning of script entry point, so further usages uses same locale

Comment: In EVERY script? Because if one script call to another the issue might arise

Comment: On every entry point. So if it's WEB app, then usually on `index.php`